# how to set the width of div through database value?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I used *ngfor to display data on screen. I want to set the width of div depends on the list.perc value. i used this below code.. but It gives error that it is unsafe.

```
    <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let list of display;let i=index;" >
 <div style="width:{{list.perc}};height:10px"></div>
    <ion-item><p style="color: #9DA4AB;">percentage {{list.perc}}</p></ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

How can i achieve this.

> Please Advise..

Answer (score 1):

Use ngStyle for styling.

```
[style.width]="list.perc+'%'"
```

Hope it will help

Comment: 'list.perc' will be defined in component.

Comment: I used this code but it works only for 100 or 0.. I have value in list like[12.33, 23.898, 50, 6.345].. how would i write percentage with it.. may be by using % it will work more accurately..

Comment: I concatenate % with list.percin ts.. [ngStyle]="{width: list.perc}"

Comment: Cool. [ngStyle] by default takes percentage. This is another way to do the same task.